# What's the difference between CheckBox and ToggleButton on a ribbon?

Tags: c#, ribbon

As far I can see, there's only one difference between a `CheckBox` and `ToggleButton` - the visual appearance on the ribbon. While the first one will be checked/unchecked, the latter will glow or not.

Moreover, when added to a menu, even the toggle button control will be rendered as a check box! No difference at all, in that case.

1. Functionality is the same: a GUI representation of a `bool`.
2. Extensibility is the same: both can be inherited and remade into a tri-state control.
3. Programmability is the same: both have the same delegate signature for event handling.

Am I missing something? In such case - what?

Comment: No, you got it and are not missing anything.

Comment: Microsoft has some guidelines on which one to use (see the section Is it the right control?): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465475.aspx

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 You comment doesn't apply to the ribbon-part of the question but still a great link. I found it very informative and well composed. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dichotomy has existed elsewhere for a long time already. Yes, functionally they're always the same. It's probably up to the specific case where they are used. E.g. if I look in Word then the document views are toggle buttons:

[image]

whereas the various things that can be shown separately (e.g. ruler, grid, etc.) are check boxes:

[image]

It seems that the toggle buttons in that case are used as radio buttons. Also a toggle button makes the current state much more visible than just a checkbox, so if a toggle choice is more important than the rest around it, then it might make sense to use it.

I'd say pick a style you're using and the criteria when you are using it and do so consistently.

Comment: Perfect answer! A bit worrying that you actually had those images ready, just in case. (Or, in case you just produced them, a larger bit worrying...) But then again, if one wants to serve the community, one has to come prepared! Thanks you.

Comment: Oh, I just fired up Word and took screenshots. I knew it had both toggle buttons and checkboxes in the ribbon :-)